# Multiple enumerations

Tags: c++, enums

I was wondering if I could use different enumerations in the same file where one is already present?

For this project I have elements which act as a genre for a number of books. I want to create different story's for the books and create a 2nd enum for them.

```
enum element {
    ICE, FIRE, EARTH, WIND, NONE
};
enum book stories {
    FK, IK, EK, WK, NONE
};
```

could this start issues with my compiler?

Comment: `enum book stories {` will cause a syntax error. Otherwise I can't see any issue with using multiple enums in a single translation unit, as long the enum tokens aren't ambigouus, or you use scoped enums.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The enumeration `NONE` is present in both `element` and `book stories` (btw, you cannot name your enums with a space inside).

#### enum class

Use `enum class`es if you want to use `NONE` in both enumerations.

```
enum class element 
{
    ICE, FIRE, EARTH, WIND, NONE
};

enum class bookstories 
{
    FK, IK, EK, WK, NONE
};
```

Then you use your enum like this:

```
auto elem  = element::NONE;
auto story = bookstories::NONE;
```

Answer (score 1):

Leaving the syntax error caused by `book stories` aside, you can make your `enum` declarations unambigous by putting them into a scope:

```
struct Elements {
    enum element {
        ICE, FIRE, EARTH, WIND, NONE
    };
};

struct BookStories {
    enum book_stories {
        FK, IK, EK, WK, NONE
    };
};
```

Referring to `Elements::NONE` and `BookStories::NONE` would be unambigous then.

---

Another way to make enums scoped is to use `enum class` (since c++11):

```
enum class element {
    ICE, FIRE, EARTH, WIND, NONE
};

enum class book_stories {
    FK, IK, EK, WK, NONE
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is most generally solved by doing this:

```
typedef enum element_e {
  E_ELEMENT_ERROR = -1,
  E_ELEMENT_NONE,
  /* ... */
} element_t;

typedef enum bookstories_e {
  E_BOOKSTORIES_ERROR = -1,
  E_BOOKSTORIES_NONE,
  /* ... */
} bookstories_t;
```

So you can maintain C / C++ interop in your header files. If you don't have any C modules, use enum classes like the other answers describe.

Comment: The entire progam is made in c++ so I will stick with the tip from @Serkan T.